# Unityでビルドすると、VR対応が自動的に外れてしまう現象

Tags: unity3d

お世話になります。
最近まで難なくビルドできていたのですが、今日ビルドしてみたら
VR対応の設定が勝手に外れてしまうことに気づきました。
ビルドしたアプリを実行しても、ヘッドマウントに表示されません。

設定が勝手に画像１になってしまうので、
画像２のように設定を直してビルドしてもまた画像１の設定に強制的に戻されます。

ビルドしたアプリを実行すると、画像３のようなエラーがでて、VRHMDで見ることができません。

どなたか解決方法をご存じないでしょうか。

ver info:
Unity 2017.3.1f
SteamVR v1.2.3
VRTK 3.2.0

[image: ビルド後、勝手にこの設定に変更されます]

[image: その後、このような設定にしてビルドしたとしても下記のエラーがでます]

[image: エラー]

Answer (score 0):

Unityのバグだったようです。
特に何もしてませんが3日後に治りました。